# What is the equivalent of "if item in list/set' in C code of a Python extension module?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, combinations, extension-modules

Writing a Python extension module which is intended to speed up execution of a function written as Python script I am stuck with the problem of how to check in C-code of a Python extension module if a C-Python object is in a C-Python set/list of C-Python objects.

In other words what I am looking after is the equivalent of Python script expression `item in list/set` in C code of a Python extension module.

Any hints how to accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: **#3 Too broad, we are not a tutoring service**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int `PySequence_Contains(PyObject *o, PyObject *value)`
>
> Determine if *o* contains *value*. If an item in *o* is equal to *value*, return `1`, otherwise return `0`. On error, return `-1`. This is equivalent to the Python expression `value in o`.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Contains)